# Convert Curl to Python | IBM STT

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying the convert the below curl command to python

`curl -X POST -u "apikey:my_key" --header "Content-Type:" --data-binary @testaudio1.wav "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?speaker_labels=true"`

The curl command is a working one but I cannot get the one corresponding to python.

I tried the below code

```
import json, sys
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

wav_file = sys.argv[1]

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    iam_apikey='my_api',
    url='https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1'
)

with open(wav_file, 'rb') as audio:
    result = speech_to_text.recognize(audio, content_type='audio/wav', timestamps=True,
        word_confidence=True, speaker_labels=True)
```

but it seems to throw an error `AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`

Answer (score 0):

Using `requests` module.

**Ex:**

```
import requests

with open(wav_file, 'rb') as audio:
    response = requests.post("https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?speaker_labels=true",
                             headers={'apikey': 'my_key'},
                             data=audio))
```

Comment: It returns me response code 413. I have used the same file in both the places. Is it because of how the wav_file is passed ?

Comment: Lazy read as in ? I tried passing the file directly as data='wav_file.wav' and the api returned 401 unauthorized

Comment: @SitharaSuresh  Use `auth=("apikey","my_key")`.